# Server/Client program in C: how to send correctly dimension of structure elements via socket?

Tags: c, sockets, structure, strlen

I have a feeling this must be a silly error due to my lack of understanding of C issues, but I am not able to find a solution.

I am quite new to C, and I am working on a Client/Server program with threadpool for an assignment. My problem is: I need to make possible that every client can see all the clients that are connected to the server by typing a command that is sent to the server. To do this, in the server I have to use a global structure that holds username and thread index of all the players involved (the use of this structure is part of the assignment specs).

This is how I defined the structure (BACKLOG is the dimension of the threadpool and also the max number of clients that can be connected at a time):

```
struct giocatori {
char* username;
int userthread;
};
struct giocatori players[BACKLOG];
```

when the client types the proper command, the command is sent to the server that calls the function that checks who is connected.
A portion of this function is giving me some trouble.

The server function browses the BACKLOG structures to check which ones are occupied. While doing that, the function *should* send to the client the following: 1)the dimension of the username of every client; 2) the username of every client. 
Unfortunately, it seems that I am doing some kind of mess with calculating the dimension, cause the function strlen() on players[i].username returns an incredibly high number (that I cant understand the origin of) and the second send fails (it returns a number different from username_dim, but still not the correct one). This is the portion of the code:

```
for(i=0; i<BACKLOG; i++) {
    if(players[i].username!="\0") {
        name=players[i].username;
        username_dim=htonl(strlen(name));
        printf("name dimension: %d\n", username_dim);
        printf("username: %s\n", name);
        ret = send(sd, &username_dim, sizeof(username_dim), 0);
        if(ret == -1 || ret < sizeof(username_dim)){ 
            close(sd);
                errore("error when sending username (dimension)");              
        }
        ret = send(sd, name, username_dim, 0);
        if(ret == -1 || ret <username_dim){ 
            printf("ret %d\n", ret);
            close(sd);
                errore("errore when sending usernam (name)");               
        }
    }
}//end for
```

Is the use of strlen() wrong? if so, what can I do to calculate the lenght of each username I have to send?

Thank you in advance.

I forgot to mention, the output of the 2 printf is (for example, with a 1 character long username):

> name dimension: 16777216 
>   username: a

I tried with different usernames, and the output of dimension is always the number of characters in the username multiplied by 16777216

Comment: Did you allocate memory to username before assigning any value to it?

Comment: no I didnt. I tried to do so with a malloc in the definition of the structure but it didnt let me. Do I have to allocate its memory directly in the thread?

Comment: yes, you need to allocate memory. What you have currently in the struct is just a pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to allocate memory to username before assigning any value to it. 
Try using malloc within your thread or even a simpler approach - replace your struct

```
struct giocatori {  
  char* username;  
  int userthread;  
};
```

with

```
struct giocatori {  
  char username[20];  //some random value for array length  
  int userthread;  
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't think I can use the second solution because in my program the usernames are sent from the clients to the server when they first log in, and so the variable I use to store them in the recv() has a dinamic allocation (sorry for my english, hope it's clear). I am trying to fix things with the malloc, thank you!